# Can i use cursor inside a cursor in sybase?

Tags: sql, sybase

i want to use cursor inside a cursor

or can i write query like

```
select t.name,t1.name 
from dbo.sysobjects as t, dbo.sysobjects as t1 
where t.name like 'a%' or t1.name like "b%a"
```

and use a single cursor to fetch the both kind of table name?

Comment: This is a cartesian query and I suppose this is wrong query.
Describe what do you want to get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a cursor inside another cursor (not recommended!).

But if that is what you want you can use a cursor with one query only.

If you want cartesian query it's like this:

```
select t.name, t1.name from dbo.sysobjects t, dbo.sysobjects t1
where t.name like 'a%' or t1.name like 'b%a'
```

If you want another type of query just tell what do you expect to see as the result.

Comment: why cursor inside cursor is not recomanded can you explain please